# Which one is correct: "have good climate" or "have a good climate"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Can you please tell me which one is correct: *have good climate* or *have a good climate*? For example:

> I'd like to live in a country that has good climate.
>
> I'd like to live in a country that has **a** good climate.

Online dictionaries list the word *climate* as being both a countable and uncountable noun, so theoretically both should work. But, I'd like to know which one is more natural: with the indefinite article or without.

Comment: As a native (U.S.) English speaker, the "... a good climate." version is more natural.

Comment: Source for dictionaries that say it's uncountable?

Comment: Dictionaries also give examples of usage.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/climate